# 24 VDC PS supplying 25 V?

Tags: power-supply, voltage

Is it typical for power adapters to vary by such a margin? I just purchased [this PS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01GC6VS8I) and my multimeter is showing 25V ±0.001 V. Is this typical or is the device defective?

Comment: It's typical. Once you add a load, I bet it goes down to 24V.

Comment: @PhilNDeBlanc Thanks; I'll add load and re-test. I'm learning lots about circuits.

Comment: That is only 4% off the advertised value, so may be within the power supply specs.  Also, meters are not perfect - yours may be reading a bit high...

Comment: I've seen even larger voltage error in power supplies without load.  For example, I've seen a 7V unloaded output from a 5V power supply.  it came down to 5V when I added load.

Comment: What is the power supply? Many power supplies  have say a +/- 5% spec some even wider and many have a minimum load for regulation.

Comment: @PhilNDeBlanc With a light load, it only dropped ~0.3 V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, 1 volt in 24 (4% error) is entirely normal. But it all depends on the power supply specifications.

A very common tolerance for power supplies is +/- 10%, which would be +/- 2.4 volts. A fairly tight spec would be 5%. However, for non-adjustable precision supplies you can find 1% units although that is rare. It is a good idea, especially for high-current units, to provide an open-circuit output slightly on the high side to allow for the inevitable voltage drop in the output wires.